# How do I make a list of field values on annotated Django queryset results?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

This may be out there somewhere, but not quite sure how to ask it. Hopefully it will be a quick one. Say I have a table like the following:

```
name         count   site
Guy Man      2       ABC
Guy Man      3       BCD
Guy Man      4       CDE
Girl Woman   2       ABC
Girl Woman   2       BCD
Girl Woman   3       CDE
```

I would like to annotate these, so that I get a name, total count, and list of sites. So given the data above, I'd get the following.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Guy Man",
    "count_total": 9,
    "site_list": "ABC, BCD, CDE"
  },
  {
    "name": "Girl Woman",
    "count_total": 7,
    "site_list": "ABC, BCD, CDE"
  }
]
```

I understand how to get `count_total`, but I'm not sure how to get `site_list`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Solution for PostgreSQL grouping by name field in combination with [`ArrayAgg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg) and the `distinct=True` flag:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates.general import ArrayAgg
from django.db.models import Count

Model.objects.values('name').annotate(
    count_total=Count('count'),
    site_list=ArrayAgg('site', distinct=True),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using postgres you can use ArrayAgg

docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/

You can use values to group by and something like the following should do the trick. `Model.objects.values('name').distinct().annotate(site_list=ArrayAgg('site'), count_total=Count('count'))`